# Angularjs multiple highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm attempting to initialise multiple highchart in an angularjs app.
The problem is that only first chart is initialise...could someone help me?

This is my directive:

```
app.directive('widget', function() {
return {
restrict: 'AC',
scope: { widgetModel: '=' },
replace: true,
template:
  '<li id="{{widgetModel.class}}" chartType="{{widgetModel.chartType}}" data-col="{{widgetModel.col}}" data-row="{{widgetModel.row}}" data-sizex="{{widgetModel.sizex}}" data-sizey="{{widgetModel.sizey}}" style="width:200px; height:100px;">'+
    '{{widgetModel.text}}, ({{widgetModel.row}},{{widgetModel.col}})'+
  '</li>',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: attrs.id,
        type: attrs.chartType,
        height: attrs.chartheight,
        animation: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [12,13,14,15],
        labels: {
          step: attrs.chartStep

        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: [1,2,3,4],
        name: "ciccio"
      }]
    });
}
  };
});
```

EDIT:

I create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/mtKJ8/33/

Comment: Any errors in console? Also, put before `var chart1 = ..` something like this: `console.log('dummy')` and let us know how many times you can see it in console. If once, `link` is called only once.

Comment: No errors in console. I see Dummy 4 in my console...

Comment: Okay, your fiddle has a lot of errors.. In general Highcharts requires one of: jQuery/prototype/mooTools. Angularjs is not supported, so you need or adapter for angularjs, or include jQuery.

Comment: I've updated my link: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/mtKJ8/33/

I've included all the missing files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]: I have update my fiddle with my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mtKJ8/59/

```
renderTo: element[0],
```